# Quick start with Murky for Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, organization, murky

I just started using Mercurial, and I'm having some difficulties. I'm using [Murky](http://bitbucket.org/snej/murky/wiki/Home) for Mercurial.

I have several projects' files at localhost, want to keep them local to work on, and then upload to a server. So:

1. Created a folder named "_reps" at localhost to keep all repositories.
2. Opened Murky app
3. Repository > New Local
4. Created rep as project name. (under _reps folder)

Now how can I add files to this project rep? How can I relate the project with this _rep, and work on changes?

Comment: hmm, I guess each rep has to be under each particular projects folder. It looks like I can't keep reps at a different path. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Mercurial, you keep your repositories generally inside the working directory (inside a .hg dir; which should be hidden by default on OS X). So I'm guessing you should just do New Local in your current project dir (not under the _reps thingy you created), then start adding files.

Comment: thanks for reply, so it is not possible to keep reps anywhere else than a project folder. thanks.